# Add directory to auto-reload in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, liquid, ruby-on-rails-5

Version: Rails 5b3

I have a folder located at `<rails root>/app/liquid`.  Inside that are more directories and `.rb` files. All the `.rb` files are simple classes with no includes or requires

It's very inconvenient to have to restart the server each time I make a change to a file in this directory, so I want these classes to be automatically reloaded every time I refresh the page. `config.eager_load_paths += ["#{Rails.root}/app/liquid"]` doesn't seem to work.

Any advice is appreciated!

---

Edit: To clarify, files in `app/liquid` autoload and reload as expected.  However, any file within a subdirectory (like `app/liquid/drops/*.rb)` autoload correctly, but do not auto-reload on page refresh

Comment: I am on rails 4 still. But here any folder under `app/` is autoloaded by default. Any changes are reflected without server restart.

Comment: @ArupRakshit The classes are loaded in just fine, but changes I make don't show up until server restart.

Comment: can you show the development.rb file? Also are you running webrick locally?

Comment: @ArupRakshit After more investigation, files in the root of `app/liquid` reload as you described.  However, files in `app/liquid/drops` do not.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Are you getting errors any? If so, please show me that error

Comment: @ArupRakshit I am not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114066/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-kieran-e).

Comment: Are you autoloading the classes using Rails' built-in autoloading mechanism? or are you manually requiring the files in app/liquid/drops/?

Comment: I'm not requiring any of the files.  I'm using Rails' autoload feature (which is to say, I haven't had to modify the dev environment file).  I'm relying on Rails automatically picking up anything in the `/app` directory

Comment: I'm suspicious that you're not using Rails' autoloading feature and instead liquid is doing its own class loading. Here's some useful docs on how class reloading is supposed to work in rails:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#loading-mechanism
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#constant-reloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding `config.autoload_paths += Dir[ Rails.root.join('app', 'liquid', '**/',) ]` to application.rb

Answer (score 0):

Try toggling liquid's cache_classes configuration so that classes are not cached in your development environment:

```
Liquid.cache_classes = false
```

source: https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/liquid-for-programmers#caching-of-classes